# Access MailChimp API 3.0 (GET)

Tags: javascript, jquery, curl, get, mailchimp

I'm trying to make a GET request through jQuery to the Mailchimp API. It seems though my custom header is not correctly set as I get a `Your request did not include an API key.` error.

It works fine if I make the request using curl on my Ubuntu machine:

```
curl --header "Authorization: apikey 709XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-us11" https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns
```

Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'apikey 709XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-us11'
    }
}).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response); // verbose
});
```

I even tried adding this above:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'apikey 709XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-us11' }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the key via Basic Auth like and as far I am aware off, You can't query it from front-end, it must be on the back-end.

Find an example in NodeJS:

```
headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(`anything:${MailChimpKey}`).toString('base64');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

MailChimp not allowed to direct access with ajax. Once make Server WebRequest. It will surely work.

Comment: Why negative ? I already implemented mailchimp oauth in my website !